# Query by specific array index

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm struggling to find the c# equivalent for this query in mongodb:

```
db.getCollection('content').find({ "MyIntArrayProp.0": { $gt: 100 } })
```

"MyIntArrayProp" is an integer array property of each document

I'm trying to query for all documents where the MyIntArrayProp array has a value at index 0 > 100.

Is this possible to replicate through the fluent interface or the strongly typed query builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer after question update:

```
var results = documents.Where(d => 
    d.MyIntArrayProp?.Count() > 0 && // array not null and has items
    d.MyIntArrayProp[0] > 100); // compare value
```

If you're absolutely sure the array can never be null and has always at least one item with index 0, then the first part of the predicate can be omitted.

Comment: The property of the documents I'm trying to filter against is an int array and I'm trying to query at a specific index within the array. I have updated the question to make it clearer